# Not all tools are activein OTB Toolbox QGIS3.4.11

Tags: qgis, orfeo-toolbox, otb-applications

I have installed OTB Tool box (OTB 8.1.2) to my QGIS 3.4.11, According to (https://gitlab.orfeo-toolbox.org/orfeotoolbox/qgis-otb-plugin) But only one tool is visible, Can any one help me out to active all tools

[image: Tool Available in OTB]